# print a value once time in foreach

Tags: php, html, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I'm new into PHP. I googled this question but cannot get value still.
I have a PHP project where

```
<?php
foreach($categories as $key => $cat){
?>

<div class="container-fluid ">
  <div class="row justify-content-around mt-5">
    <div class="card border-0" style="width: 25rem;">
    <div class="display-3"><?php echo $cat ?></div>
    <img style="margin-bot: 100px;" class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/drinks3.png" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card border-0" style="width: 25rem;">
  <div class="display-3"><?php echo $cat ?></div>
    <img class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/snacks.png" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card border-0" style="width: 25rem;">
  <div class="display-3"><?php echo $cat ?></div>
    <img class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/postres1.png" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to print each value once time to get a card with each category of $categories. 
But im getting 9 cards with each category repeated 3 times.
I tried with index but it only get broken with offset 0.

Comment: Well that is what you have coded!! So what did you actually want

Comment: Because you print every loop three cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the nested div you need to be unique in a loop:

```
<div class="container-fluid ">
  <div class="row justify-content-around mt-5">
<?php
foreach($categories as $key => $cat){
?>
    <div class="card border-0" style="width: 25rem;">
    <div class="display-3"><?php echo $cat ?></div>
    <img style="margin-bot: 100px;" class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/drinks3.png" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
    </div>
  </div>
<?php } ?> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to you! I didn't notice I can generate a foreach inside row. I tough it will generate 3 differents row.